# Possible to click on a div to generate a select box on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive site. In it I have a select field made up of li's because I can't style an actual select input.

what I would like to do is have it be an actual select on mobile (mainly so it behaves as a select with all the options showing up in a popup instead of a dropdown). But since I can't style the select on mobile I would like to create a div or button that I can style and have that be the trigger for the select options list. is this possible? if not is there another way of doing this?

I'm mostly a css guy so I'm sure there might be a way to do this through jquery or javascript but no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try jQuery Mobile.

read this : jquery mobile 
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/

```js
$("#select-custom-1").change(function() {

  var selected_val = $("#select-custom-1 option:selected").val();

  //your code here :)
  alert(selected_val);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <label for="select-custom-1">Basic:</label>
  <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
    <option id="val1" value="1">The 1st Option</option>
    <option id="val2" value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
    <option id="val3" value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
    <option id="val4" value="4">The 4th Option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this. this will trigger a select list from click action for mobile.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <select id= 'my_select' name='my_select'>   
              <option id = 'option_A'  value = 'A' selected> A </option>
              <option id = 'option_B'  value = 'B'> B </option>
            </select>
            <a data-role="button" id="test-button">Trigger select box slick</a>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

**the JS**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $("#test-button").on( "click", function(event, ui) {
      $('#my_select option#option_B').trigger('click');    
    });

    $("#my_select option").each(function(){
        $(this).on( "click", function(event, ui) {
          $(this).attr('selected' , true);
          $('#my_select').selectmenu('refresh');                
        });         
    });    
});
```